# Ninject with WebAPI and WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ninject, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create an application that will **self host** several endpoints, some will use **WebApi** and some other **Wcf**.

The dependencies are registred with **Ninject**. I'm using the following Nuget packages: *Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.SelfHost* (for WCF) and *Ninject.Web.WebAPi.SelfHost* (for WebAPI).

Everything is working fine if I'm using WCF **OR** WebAPI. But as soon as I try to host my endpoints with WCF **AND** WebAPI , I've got an activation exception:

*An exception occured in console application. See stacktrace for more info.|Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating HttpSelfHostConfiguration using implicit self-binding of HttpSelfHostConfiguration
Several constructors have the same priority. Please specify the constructor using ToConstructor syntax or add an Inject attribute.
Constructors:
HttpSelfHostConfiguration(string baseAddress)
HttpSelfHostConfiguration(Uri baseAddress)
Activation path:
  1) Request for HttpSelfHostConfiguration
Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that the implementation type has a public constructor.
  2) If you have implemented the Singleton pattern, use a binding with InSingletonScope() instead.*

I understand what the problem is (the two nugets packages are registrering plugin, and one of them has a constructor that cannot be injected), but I have no idea on how I could fix this.

As information, the exception is thrown in the Boostrapper class, by running the following method:
`kernelInstance.Components.GetAll<INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin>()`

My current code (**WCF** registration):

```
   NinjectWcfConfiguration config = NinjectWcfConfiguration.Create<EmployeeService, NinjectServiceSelfHostFactory>(ConfigureService, this.GetBaseAddresses().ToArray());
   NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper selfHost = new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(() => this.Kernel, config);
   selfHost.Start();
```

**WebAPI** Registration:

```
    HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(new Uri(BASE_ADDRESS));
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectSelfHostDependencyResolver(this.Kernel);
    new NinjectWebApiSelfHost(config).Start();
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might want to consider also posting this on the ninject group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ninject) and maybe as an issue @ ninject issue tracker (or the respective ninject extension).

Comment: Thank you for your message and sorry for the late answer, I was on holidays. I will post on the ninject group as you suggest... cheers.

Comment: I left a comment here: https://github.com/remogloor/Ninject.Web.WebApi/issues/14